# What are the differences between "write something" & "write about something"?

Tags: word-usage

[In the dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/write)

> 1 BOOK/ARTICLE/POEM ETCa) [intransitive, transitive] to produce a new
>   book, article, poem etc
>
> He wrote some very famous books.
>
> Who wrote ‘Harry Potter’?
>
> I can’t come with you – I have an essay to write.
>
> **write about** O'Brien often writes about her native Ireland.
>
> **well/badly/poorly etc written**   The article is very well written.

The dictionary also says

> GRAMMAR: Patterns with write • You write to someone: She writes to me
>   every month.
>
> • In American English, you can also write someone: She writes me every
>   month.
>
> • You write someone a letter, note, story etc: Please write me a
>   letter soon. ✗Don’t say: Please write to me a letter soon.
>
> • You write to someone **about** a subject or an experience: He wrote to
>   me about his trip to France. ✗Don’t say: He wrote to me his trip to
>   France.
>
> • Write is often used in the progressive: I am writing to tell you
>   something important.

We say "**write articles**" but I don't think we say "**write about articles**"

But we say "**write about the trip**" but not "**write the trip**"

It seems that we "**write a general thing**" but "**write about a specific story / experience**"

But that is my guess, I am not sure

What are the differences between "**write something**" & "**write about something**"?

Answer (score 4):

When you *write something*, the something is that which you write, an essay, a poem, a novel, a paper, an article, a word or two.

When you *write about something*, the something is a topic or subject.

Comment: You can also write something into something.

Answer (score 1):

Simple!

When you right something, the thing is your object. Like "**writing an essay**". It might be abstract anyway, but still it's the object and you write that object itself; you create it.

When you right about something, there's a certain subject, you describe it, write quotes about it, an so on.